# How to scroll beyond the focused element in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll, antd

I am working on a React App, and using antd as the UI-library. What I intend to do is whenever a button named `Open Modal` is clicked, a Modal will open up, and when user clicks on the `Ok` button in the modal, an input field will be displayed and page should automatically be scrolled to the top. However, since the input field contains focus, the scroll happens only until the input field becomes visible. Is there any way to make the page scroll to top, ignoring focused elements using JS only. This is the minimal code to reproduce the example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [isInputVisible, setIsInputVisible] = useState(false);
  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    setIsInputVisible(true);
    window.scroll(0, 0);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsInputVisible(false);
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
      >
        /*Some contents...*/
        {isInputVisible && <input autoFocus />}
        /*Some contents...*/
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

This is the sandbox link to reproduce the use-case.
[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4165-forked-uq4eu?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `scrollIntoView` method.

[scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

I tried with `ref` and `useRef` but it didnt work, so the other solution was to find the modal through it's class name and use the above method.

Check this
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4165-forked-27i7h)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work but I think you can work your way through with the useRef hook where you can focus after the click event. [Refer this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: it doesnt work. it returns `current: null`. tried it too. check my sandbox. i have it in comments